# Simple tests to detect muscle imbalances between quads and hamstrings

Tags: muscle

Are there any simple tests you can do at home to check if you have some muscle imbalances between hamstrings and quads? I.e. to test if your quads are too weak compared to your hamstrings or the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The [**Klatt Test**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTK_qe11RLg), although not specific to quad/hamstrings, will give you a good idea of your overall functional lower extremity muscle balance. Basically, you jump down from varying heights on one leg and determine if you land solidly or if you lean or hop in different directions.  For example, if you hop forward on landing, your hamstrings may be weak [see page 37 of this Structural Balance pdf to interpret test results](http://www.charlespoliquin.com/portals/0/pdf/StructuralStoryHiRes.pdf).
- **Quad-Hamstring Ratio**:  As for the quad-hamstring ratio, when tested on an isokinetic Cybex machine, 3:2 is noted as the appropriate ratio.  However, depending on various factors, such as if the ACL is weak, you may want more of a 1:1 ratio.  The ratio also will depend on the type of sport or activity you do, so an ideal ratio is difficult to say given the variables. Your could do a max [quad extension](http://exrx.net/Articulations/Knee.html#anchor22459) vrs max [hamstring curl](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Hamstrings/LVLyingLegCurlH.html) to determine your ratio, but in terms of function, the Klatt test will probably give you better information.